# Poner identificador a cada grupo de una consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen día a todos solicito de valiosa ayuda, tengo el siguiente problema,

Necesito agrupar registros y a la vez poner un identificadicador (ID) para cada grupo, es decir algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intenté hacer con PARTITION BY de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT a.no_cred, a.nombre, a.nivel, a.grado, a.grupo 
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  a.nivel, a.grado, a.grupo ORDER BY  a.nivel, a.grado, a.grupo) AS id_grupo
FROM alumnos;
```

Pero me enumera cada registro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco de antemano todos sus comentarios

Gracias!

Comment: Intenta usando GROUP BY

Comment: Aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Usa `dense_rank() over( order by nivel, grado, grupo )`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Lilibeth Q, eso resolvió el problema y muchas gracias también Sal probé tu propuesta y también funciona Mil gracias